# django retrieveing user objects

Tags: django

I have a simple model like this:

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Item(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction)
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()

class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

users place bids for an item. Knowing that a user is allowed to place just one bid for each item. If I have the auction id, can I get all **user objects** (not simple usernames, like in a `values_list()`) that placed a bid in that auction?

EDIT: I would also like to avoid using 'in'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
users = User.objects.filter(bid__item__auction_id=auction_id)
```

Comment: but `bid` field is not part of the `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible to do it much easier, but this is the way I would try.

Add related names:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Auction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Item(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction,related_name="items")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.FloatField()

class Bid(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,related_name="bids")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="bids")
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Now, if you have these:

```
a = Auction.objects.get(pk=auction_id)
users = set([]) #because there's no reason to have dupe users
for item in a.items.all():
    for bid in item.bids.all():
        users.add(bid.user)
```

Now, all the users with one or more bids in that auction is in the list

Comment: xpanta: Daniel's answer works if you add related names the way I did, and change his sentence to: 

    users = User.objects.filter(bids__item__auction=auction_id)